# How do I read in a CSV file into R?

Tags: r, csv

I'm having some technical issues with loading a CSV file into R. When I inspect the csv file in RStudio's Source pane, all the characters are surrounded by weird red circles or dots. When I inspect another self-made CSV file, the characters appear perfectly fine, without any of the red circles.

What is this issue/symptom, and what would be the best way to fixing this for about 40 similar CSV files?

When I try to run `readfile <- read.csv("filename.csv", sep="", collapse=NULL)` I get the following error:

`Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
  empty beginning of file`

Comment: Why are you not using a separator, if it's a CSV?

Comment: IO think you're going to have to post a link to a portion of the file, unfortunately, or a paste of a few lines if they aren't non-standard characters.

Comment: I have no idea where the `IO` came from. It was supposed to be `I unfortunately`…

Comment: What is `readLines("filename.csv", n = 2)`?

Comment: Most likely this is a problem with the file encoding. In addition to what WD_R suggested below, you might want to add argument fileEncoding="XXX" to your `read.csv()` command. XXX there means the name of the encoding for the file. You can get a list of available ones with the R command `iconvlist()`. If you post the output from what Hugh suggested, it might be possible to figure out the correct file encoding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess would be that you ran into some encoding issue. 
Especially on Windows you can run into all sorts of problems with that. 
Try opening the csv file with a text editor that has the capability of saving files with various Encodings (e.g. Notpead++) then change that to e.g. UTF-8 (which is the preferred Encoding of RStudio most other Editors and R itself), save the file and try to run the import again. 
Just make sure that you don't loose characters - especially special characters tend to get lost during Encoding changes.

Greetings ...

Comment: Thanks, looks like the encoding was the problem. I changed it to UTF-8 like you suggested and R reads the files perfectly. Thanks